# Configuring SharePoint 2013 with Thinktecture identity provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, trusted-identity-provider

I have configured SharePoint Server 2013 with Thinktecture identity server 2 by following this article.

http://www.wictorwilen.se/using-sharepoint-2013-with-thinktecture-identityserver-2

Everything seems to work correctly. The only problem I have is that "Role" is not sent to SharePoint as a claim. Following are the Claims I am getting from Thinktecture identity provider.

[image]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or missing?